# Burnination request: [stockquotes]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I'm looking at a tag called [stockquotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stockquotes) with 133 questions. This information may be relevant to the question, but it does not add value as a separate tag.

Can we burninate this tag? Comments?

Comment: A lot of off-topic questions (asking for off-site resources) are using that tag.

Comment: Also way too many "Too Broad" type questions (closed or not).

Comment: Most other questions are about CSV parsing, SQL queries, or Yahoo Finance, so they can keep using those specific tags.

Comment: Please make sure we close and delete the questions that need it before we remove any tags. This tag looks pretty ripe for pruning.

Comment: What does the [status-completed] tag on this mean? There are still 133 questions tagged.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Rescinded. It looks like this was marked complete by mistake.

Comment: The [Stocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stocks) tag belongs in the same fire as stockquotes.

Comment: @DanNeely I'll bring the marshmallows!

Comment: Alright.. elephant in the room: How's this actually carried out? At my rep level, I can only propose edits and raise flags - that would just be doubling the mods' work.

Comment: Go ahead and suggest edits on those questions that can be salvaged. You can flag for closure on those that are off-topic, or are otherwise unsalvageable.